# Crystal Report database field convert to parameter field

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

Is it possible to convert database field to a parameter field? Or quick way to do it?

Only thing I'm aware of is removing the database connection which will remove all the database fields and then I would have to manually type out the parameters which is time consuming task as having to re-position the parameter field on screen.

Basically, we have 100 or so bespoke label created in Crystal Reports. So, I wouldn't really like to do it for them all manually. The database fields are all same in all labels.

Comment: Parameters are something that needs to be created by user....to the extent i know you can't directly convert databse to parameter fields

Comment: I feared this was the actual case. Thanks for your response.

Comment: One way....kay be rough way of doing create 1 parameter and duplicate it... one more question may be out of scope... but are you realling creating 100 plus parameters?

Comment: There are 14 database fields (generally about 6 of them are used on label) and there are 104 labels in total for each one of our customers. Generally the only difference is each label has their company logo and re-positioned fields. So, I would have to repeat this task for each label 104 times. Hope that makes more sense.